# computedFrom a signal?

Tags: aurelia

is it possible to base a @computedFrom on a signal? something like:

```
@computedFrom({signals: ["mySignalKey"]})
```

or

```
@signaledFrom("mySignalKey1", "mySignalKey2")
```

It would help in a use case where I have a property whose value is computed from a property on each of many objects in an array of objects.

(Or maybe there is already a better way?)

Comment: I know there has been a suggestion to base such a computed on a backing property, but that seems a bit like a hack to me, though relatively simple, I know.

Comment: let me know if this solution worked for you, upvote and accept if so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `@computedFrom` and `signal` tell the binding system when to update. `@computedFrom` solves a specific problem, *updating when a property changes*, and `signal` solves a general problem, *updating whenever a signal is fired*. Therefore, you can do everything with `signal` that you can do with `@computedFrom`, and so don't need to use both.

In order to signal an update to the binding system for a computed value, use a function to compute the value, with the following pattern:

**transactions.html**

```
<table>
    <tr repeat.for="entry of transactions">
        <td>${entry.value}</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td>Total: ${getTotal() & signal: 'value-update'}</td></tr>
</table>
```

**transactions.js**

```
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { BindingSignaler } from 'aurelia-templating-resources';

@inject(BindingSignaler)
export class TransactionsViewModel {

    constructor(BindingSignaler) {
        this.signaler = BindingSignaler;
        this.transactions = window.fetch('transactions');
    }

    // call somewhere to update a particular entry by a particular amount, 
    // and signal to the binding system to recompute the total
    updateValue(entry, amount) {
        entry.value += amount;
        this.signaler.signal('value-update');
    }

    // sums the values of all transactions
    getTotal() {
        return this.transactions.reduce((value, entry) => value + entry.value, 0);
    }
}
```

See the gist: https://gist.run/?id=d6c534d7b0a1b26fc3f27366b0e5b7a2

Comment: If this answers your question, please don't forget to accept and upvote. If I've misunderstood your question, please clarify in your original question and I'll revisit this answer.

Comment: Thanks Matthew.  This answer relies on dirty checking to evaluate whether the `total` computed property has changed.  I'm trying to avoid that -- the whole idea behind using @computedFrom.  If I could specify that the propery should be reevaluted based on the signal, then I'd be solving the problem of dirty checking.

Comment: You're right. Let me see if I can get a better answer for you. Sorry about that. Gist here: https://gist.run/?id=aa5188c1ffd6f180d7dba4ffbc004cca

Comment: @DougKent Fixed. Take another look. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Thanks, but where should I look?  The gist doesn't really have anything pertinent.

Comment: the gist in the comments is the old example and demonstrates that you are in fact correct. the gist in the answer demonstrates the new answer in practice. you'll notice there's a console.log line in the getTotal code. you can check the console to see how often the getTotal function is being called. you'll notice in the answer, the getTotal function is only called when the signal is fired.

Comment: I am clicking on the link in your answer, [here](https://gist.run/?id=94882aba26cfe8a006460e8c426c8b2f) and I see the "checked" console output being issued constantly.

Comment: sorry! the comment above should be https://gist.run/?id=94882aba26cfe8a006460e8c426c8b2f. I've updated the answer.

Comment: hi guys, i've adjusted the gist furthermore so now getTotal() doesn't get dirty checked:
https://gist.run/?id=51deb418e8ea31b6e7ec443442539acc

Comment: um? it wasn't getting dirty checked before? why is everyone seeing the wrong gist :(

Comment: not in the answer...
https://gist.run/?id=1411e62fd8b6636394e21ba8b199e21d

Comment: in case you're having trouble reading the log, I've added an actual "count" variable and incremented it in place of logging, so you can see in the output: https://gist.run/?id=d6c534d7b0a1b26fc3f27366b0e5b7a2

Comment: Please see "Addressing the answer from Matthew", below.

Answer (score 1):

Addressing the answer from Matthew James Davis: OK, what you've done differently here is that instead of using a computed property for the total, you're calling a function "getTotal()".

This doesn't really solve the problem I was looking for, it only works around it by using a function instead of a computed property.  My question was specifically posed as pertaining to a computed property.

In other words, I expected an answer that would allow me to continue using a computed property.

But I realize that my question was perhaps not really fair, that perhaps it really should be posed as a feature request for Aurelia.  So, in appreciation for your efforts, and assuming that a better answer really isn't forthcoming, I'm going to go ahead and mark yours as an answer.

Comment: A computed property is just a function.

Answer (score 0):

adding `& oneTime` to the expression :
https://gist.run/?id=51deb418e8ea31b6e7ec443442539acc

Comment: "checked" has been logged over 13k times, while I ate lunch.  ;-)

Comment: I don't see "oneTime" in there anywhere....in any case, oneTime will prevent the Total from being updated by the signal

Comment: oops,was my first gist run (hijacked from matthew's gist) didn't save it. pls check again:
https://gist.run/?id=51deb418e8ea31b6e7ec443442539acc

Comment: @DougKent  didn't you had lunch today? ;)

Comment: oneTime is there now, thanks, but again, it prevents the Total from being updated by the signal.  Add this to the html and you can see:

`<div><input type="number" value.bind="transactions[0].value"></div>`

Comment: hmm...works here on chrome...seeing list entry and total updated (using the signal)

Comment: It doesn't work for me, in chrome.  Url:  https://gist.run/?id=51deb418e8ea31b6e7ec443442539acc

Comment: http://imgur.com/mAoNy1n
as you can see, same gist and 
this.signaler.signal('value-update') -> causes the total to be updated (proof: if i uncomment it it doesn't work anymore)